Does a bundle $\mathcal V_{\Gamma}$ tell us something about $\zeta_{\Gamma}(u)$?
From what I understand the Ihara zeta function, $\zeta_{\Gamma}(u)$, is obtained from a graph (or multigraph $\Gamma$) irrespective of an embedding. So, what changes if $\Gamma$ is embedded in $\Bbb R^3$ as a topological multigraph (i.e. edges are smooth curves)? How would this affect a meromorphic extension of $\zeta_{\Gamma}(u)$? With smooth edges we can enrich $\Gamma$ with a line bundle $\mathcal V_{\Gamma}$ and furnish this bundle with a connection $\nabla.$
I was thinking that the fixed points under the action of the holonomy group $\mathrm{Hol}_{\nabla}(\mathcal V_{\Gamma})$ might encode information about the poles/zeros of $\zeta_{\Gamma}(u).$

Does $\mathcal V_{\Gamma}$ or a complexification of $\mathcal V_{\Gamma}$ tell us anything about $\zeta_{\Gamma}(u)?$

